# lost all the changes in eclipse using maven svn

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I am using svm and maven in eclipse and I have lost all the work I did in past 4 months Is there a way I could change the whole project like it was a day before?

Comment: *Four months* worth of work? Did you SVN server explode or something? At any rate unless something extremely bad happened to the SVN repository, you should always be able to check out any previous version.

Comment: I used replace with option available in eclipse and updated to current svn url version. I never used the commit option.

Comment: You've been working for four months without committing even once?

Comment: I could really use some help anything

Answer (score 0):

Running on Windows? Have you tried looking if there's previous versions of it? On Windows 7, right click on the folder that had your project, properties, previous versions. In Windows 8, try looking for "File History".

Other than that, I can think of nothing. :(